# Error when freeing memory

Tags: c

I am writing some code to compute the sum of fibonacci values up to n, as stored in an array. For only certain values of n, I get an error on calling free().

Edit: This code should now compile.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

long fib(long *fibs, int n);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  long num, sum;
  long n;
  long *fibs;

  if(argc < 2) {
    printf("Usage %s n\n", argv[0]);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
  }

  n = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
  printf("%ld\n", n);

  printf("--Allocating memory\n");
  fibs = (long *) malloc(sizeof(long) * n);
  printf("--Memory allocated\n");

  fibs[0] = 1;
  fibs[1] = 1;

  sum = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    num = fib(fibs, i);
    sum += num;

    printf("%ld\n", num);
  }

  printf("%ld\n", sum);

  printf("--Freeing memory\n");
  free(fibs);
  printf("--Memory freed\n");
}

long fib(long *fibs, int n) {
  if((n == 0) || (n == 1)) {
    return 1;
  }

  fibs[n] = fibs[n - 1] + fibs[n - 2];
  return fibs[n];
}
```

For instance, when I call the program ./fibsum with n=5, I get a core dump.

Comment: what is `n` in main? please post a minimal compilable code, there are so many problems in your code

Comment: Do not cast the return of malloc. And you should initialise fibs when declaring it.

Also this doesn't declare i so I'm not sure how it compiles

Comment: The code as shown does not compile.

Comment: You should probably be using `malloc(n * sizeof(long))` rather than `malloc(n * sizeof(n))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like i told you in the comments, you are overflowing when using <= instead of < in the loop. Take a look at the following example, this is by no means trying to be a "cleaned up" version of your code, I just made it work without changing too much.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int number = 300;

long* fib(long* fibs, int n)
{
    if (n == 0 || n == 1)
    {
        fibs[n] = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        fibs[n] = (fibs[n-1] + fibs[n-2]);
    }
    return fibs;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    long* fibs = (long*)malloc(number * sizeof(long));
    long sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < number; ++i) //changed <= to < like i said in the comments
    {
        sum += fib(fibs, i)[i];
        printf("%d\n", sum);
    }

    printf("\n\nSum of everything: %ld\n", sum);
    free(fibs); //no problem

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The lines

```
  fibs[n] = 1;
```

and

```
 fibs[n] = fibs[n - 1] + fibs[n - 2];
```

modify memory beyond the legal range. The legal range is `fibs[0]` - `fibs[n-1]`. Due to that, the program displays undefined behavior. In your case, the undefined behavior manifests in the form of problem in the call to `free`.

You may want to allocate one more element than you are currently allocating. Instead of

```
fibs = (long *) malloc(n * sizeof(n));
```

use

```
fibs = malloc((n+1) * sizeof(n));
```

See an SO post on [why you should not cast the return value of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: Why is that, he used if((n == 0) || (n == 1)) which means n-1 will be index 1 and n-2 will be index 0 or am i missing something

Comment: @CamelToe, I did not follow your question.

Comment: _modify memory beyond the legal range_ how? @RSahu

Comment: @rakeb.void, the `for` loop in `main` goes from `0` to `n`, not `0` to `n-1`. As a consequence, the posted code will modify `fibs[n]`.

Comment: Don't cast `malloc` result, it's unnecessary! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Answer (score 1):

There are number of problems -

1. `i` is undeclared in `main`.
2. `n` is not declared in `main`.
3. And most important one this loop-

   ```
    for(i = 0; i <= n; i++)
   ```

As you allocate memory for `n` items but loop goes from `0` to `n` .You forgot it should be  till `n-1` .Thus behaviour is undefined.

As case you described (`n=5` so loop should be from `0 to 4`).

Answer (score 0):

There are few problems in your code, some are typing mistake I guess, some are logical problem:

- You forgot to type `n` and `i`
- Never cast `malloc`, so instead of `fibs = (long *) malloc(n * sizeof(n));` try `fibs = malloc(n * sizeof(long));`
- In the for loop, instead of `for(i = 0; i <= n; i++)` use `for(i = 0; i < n; i++)`
- `sum += fib(fibs, i);` here, `sum` is `long` but `fib()` returns `long *`, so change function defalcation `long *fib(long *fibs, int n)` to `long fib(long *fibs, int n)`

I update your code then [run](http://ideone.com/YVruyj) and get output : ***12***.

The modified code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

long fib(long *fibs, int n) {
   if((n == 0) || (n == 1)) {
      fibs[n] = 1;
   } else {
       fibs[n] = fibs[n - 1] + fibs[n - 2];
   }
   return fibs[n];
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   long *fibs;
   long sum = 0;
   int n = 6, i;
   fibs = malloc(n * sizeof(long));
   long tem;

   for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       tem = fib(fibs, i);
       sum += tem;
   }

   printf("%ld\n", sum);
   free(fibs);
}
```